# How to modify upload button in Dropzone.js?

Tags: css, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="/upload" class="dropzone text-black" id="my-dropzone">
</form>
```

JS:

```
import Dropzone from "dropzone";
import "dropzone/dist/dropzone.css";
const myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
```

This creates a basic area like this:

[image]

Adding images works like a charm:

[image]

However, I would like to use a different design, like this:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-900/25 px-6 py-10">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <svg class="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-gray-300" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.5 6a2.25 2.25 0 012.25-2.25h16.5A2.25 2.25 0 0122.5 6v12a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.25 2.25H3.75A2.25 2.25 0 011.5 18V6zM3 16.06V18c0 .414.336.75.75.75h16.5A.75.75 0 0021 18v-1.94l-2.69-2.689a1.5 1.5 0 00-2.12 0l-.88.879.97.97a.75.75 0 11-1.06 1.06l-5.16-5.159a1.5 1.5 0 00-2.12 0L3 16.061zm10.125-7.81a1.125 1.125 0 112.25 0 1.125 1.125 0 01-2.25 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                    <div class="mt-4 flex text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
                        <label for="file-upload" class="relative cursor-pointer rounded-md bg-white font-semibold text-indigo-600 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-indigo-600 focus-within:ring-offset-2 hover:text-indigo-500">
                            <span>Upload a file</span>
                            <input id="file-upload" name="file-upload" type="file" class="sr-only">
                        </label>
                        <p class="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-600">PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB</p>
                </div>
            </div>`
```

How can I use my custom design with dropzone.js?

I tried to add the id to the outer div of my upload area:

```
<form action="upload" class="  mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-900/25 px-6 py-10" id="my-dropzone">
```

But when using my custom design, clicking on the image does not trigger the upload:
[image]

Also, when uploading images, the whole layout gets broken:

[image]

Comment: Opening the file upload dialog usually happens due to the label getting clicked, but the SVG image is not part of your label.